# ExcelWebPart Issue

Tags: web-part, excel, edit

I'm using ExcelWebpart in my page and I defined permissions on the webpart. Some users can edit the excel webpart. They click "OPEN IN EXCEL" and then they can edit.

But today when they click on the "OPEN IN EXCEL", they got

> Sorry, server could you not open ...\kanstok.xsl

And Excel didn't open. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Excel file remained locked. I lifted the locks fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for getting back with your solution. Can you please elaborate what the "lifted the locks" means in practice.

Comment: I opened for edit lock files, lock resolved.All I do is this